# How to save image which sent via flask send_file

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have this code for server

```
@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    return send_file("token.jpg", attachment_filename=("token.jpg"), mimetype='image/jpg')
```

and this code for getting response

```
r = requests.get(url + '/get')
```

And i need to save file from response to hard drive. But i cant use r.files. What i need to do in these situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the get request is valid. You can use use Python's built in function [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), to open a file in binary mode and  write the returned content to disk. Example below.

```
file_content = requests.get('http://yoururl/get')
save_file = open("sample_image.png", "wb")
save_file.write(file_content.content)
save_file.close()
```

As you can see, to write the image to disk, we use [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and write the returned content to 'sample_image.png'. Since your server-side code seems to be returning only one file, the example above should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [stream parameter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and extract the filename from the HTTP headers. Then the raw data from the undecoded body can be read and saved chunk by chunk.

```
import os
import re 
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get', stream=True)
name = re.findall('filename=(.+)', resp.headers['Content-Disposition'])[0]
dest = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), name)
with open(dest, 'wb') as fp:
    while True:
        chunk = resp.raw.read(1024)
        if not chunk: break
        fp.write(chunk)
```